# No suitable driver found for jdbc.sqlite,more complicated

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I am writing a program to connect to a database using java and SQLite. I have tried anything I came across but nothing seems to help.
The code looks like this:

```
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import org.sqlite.JDBC;

    /**
     *
     * @author sqlitetutorial.net
     */

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public class SQLiteJDBCDriverConnection {
         /**
         * Connect to a sample database
         */
        public static void connect() {
            Connection conn = null;
            try {
                // db parameters
                String url = "jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\marks\\Desktop\\sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3180000\\SQLiteStudio\\chinook.db";
                // create a connection to the database
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

                System.out.println("Connection to SQLite has been established.");

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (conn != null) {
                        conn.close();
                    }
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            connect();
        }
    }
```

And the error I am getting is:

```
    org.sqlite.JDBC
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at SQLiteJDBCDriverConnection.main(SQLiteJDBCDriverConnection.java:42)
```

[image: The picture showing the driver]

I have followed the exact steps from http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/sqlite-jdbc-driver/ and it doesn't work for me!

I am using Eclipse Java Neon(latest) on Widows 10 64-bit.

Comment: You need the JDBC driver in your build path.

Comment: How are you running your application. The error indicates you don't have the SQLite JDBC driver on the classpath at runtime.

Comment: That error is incomplete, post the full stacktrace. Also why are you continuing to connect if SQLite driver class was not found?

Comment: @m0skit0 It might not be complete, but the stacktrace itself suggests it is a `ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: @MarkRotteveel It does, but let's make sure it is.

Answer (score -2):

**EDITED**

As your tutorial show, you just need to call `connect()` method on main void.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        connect();
}
```

You are trying to retrieve the class `Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");` and you are not using it later.

Comment: He is calling `connect()` in his main method, I'm not sure how this addresses the problem. And nothing in the question suggests tomcat is involved. And putting things in `%JAVA_HOME%/lib` is **not** how you should handle classpath problems with Java.

Comment: You are right, i do edit the answer, anyway he is calling connect after try to search `org.sqlite.JDBC` class. I do think that he does not need to retrieve this class and it fails just there. It is crashing before call connect method

Comment: Your edit makes it worse, the connection string with prefix `jdbc:sqlite:` uses the driver `org.sqlite.JDBC`. And although it is no longer necessary to use `Class.forName` to load JDBC 4 (or higher) drivers, the fact that doing this throws a `ClassNotFoundException` means that this driver is not on the classpath. In other words, you are not addressing the problem at all.